# How to generate guid from DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to generate a Guid v.1 from a `DateTime`. I try to use the class described here:

> https://gist.github.com/nberardi/3759706

But after getting a `DateTime` from a `Guid`, I tried to get the same `Guid` as the original using that `DateTime`, and it gave me a different `Guid`. Here's the code I used:

```
  string uuidString = "9e5713bb-bb4c-11e8-9d6c-12345678df23";
  Guid gui = new Guid(uuidString);
  DateTime dateTimeFromGuid = GuidGenerator.GetDateTime(gui);
  Console.WriteLine(dateTimeFromGuid.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
  Guid guidFromDateTime = GuidGenerator.GenerateTimeBasedGuid(dateTimeFromGuid);
  Console.WriteLine(guidFromDateTime); //7909dbbb-bb33-11e8-9f6a-95d8e90ccf10
```

How can I get the original GUID back from a `DateTime`?

Comment: The code you link to has a method for doing that, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @DavidG `Guid GenerateTimeBasedGuid(DateTime dateTime)` generate other guid.

Comment: It doesn't... it works perfectly fine for me... see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oQ9TTP (i just copy/pasted the gist and your code) . You are probably doing something else

Comment: @Jcl That fiddle generates a random new guid every time (run it multiple times and you'll see), so what's the point?

Comment: @spender I am seeing the GUID change too, like Camilo

Comment: For me, the Guid that is printed in the Fiddle changes with every run.

Comment: It is changing. Ignore me.

Comment: 4 & 5 octets may be other, but why 1-3 other too? they are generated via dateTime.

Comment: The GUID cannot be reconstructed from the date/time alone. Look at `node` in the source for what you link to.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError 1-3 octet can. and you can see this in `https://dotnetfiddle.net/oQ9TTP`. but on my PC ALL octets are other. why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to get reproducible GUIDs, then you need to disable the random components. These are set when the program starts. After that they no longer change, so the generated GUIDs are stable from then on, but each run of the program will use different random values, so each run will give a different semi-random GUID for a known datetime value.

To disable it, simply do:

```
//var random = new Random();
//random.NextBytes(DefaultClockSequence);
//random.NextBytes(DefaultNode);
```

Furthermore when running it locally, you have to force your DateTime value to use UTC, which I did as follows:

```
DateTime dateTimeFromGuid = GuidGenerator.GetDateTime(gui);
dateTimeFromGuid = new DateTime(dateTimeFromGuid.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

It would be much better to move this "UTC fix" into the library code.

Fiddle (I also changed the input GUID to a "non-randomized" value):
https://dotnetfiddle.net/niIHlz

Comment: A you got `9e5713bb-bb4c-11e8 - ..` value on PC ?

Comment: I noticed a discrepancy in GUIDs when running locally, caused by timezones. If you force the timezone to UTC then it should work regardless of timezone. See the update.

Comment: Looks  like situation, when every tick can change output guid. Correct?

Answer (score 6):

If you want something simple that can be converted back and forth regardless of what machine you are on. Then, you can convert the date to a byte array and use that to create the `Guid`. This is non-standard, but will generate the same exact `Guid` for each `DateTime`.

```
var today = new DateTime(2018, 9, 18, 10, 59, 00);

var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(today.Ticks);

Array.Resize(ref bytes, 16);

var guid = new Guid(bytes);

Console.WriteLine(guid); //bd02b200-1d55-08d6-0000-000000000000
```

And back to date.

```
var dateBytes = guid.ToByteArray();

Array.Resize(ref dateBytes, 8);

var date = new DateTime(BitConverter.ToInt64(dateBytes));

Console.WriteLine(date); //9/18/2018 10:59:00
```

If you want to use extensions then.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2018, 09, 18, 12, 00, 00);

        var guid = date.ToGuid();

        Console.WriteLine(guid); // 428a6000-1d5e-08d6-0000-000000000000

        var back2date = guid.ToDateTime();

        Console.WriteLine(back2date); // 9/18/2018 12:00:00
    }
}

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static Guid ToGuid(this DateTime dt)
    {
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(dt.Ticks);

        Array.Resize(ref bytes, 16);

        return new Guid(bytes);
    }
}

public static class GuidExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this Guid guid)
    {
        var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();

        Array.Resize(ref bytes, 8);

        return new DateTime(BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Guids/UUIDs [have versioning info in them and follow standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions). By effectively cramming random data (or datetime data) into the bytes of a Guid, you're creating something that is non-standard. You're also creating a Guid with 8 zero bytes. I'm not so sure about this.

Comment: and you can get back `bd02b200-1d55-08d6-0000-00000000` value from you date ?

Comment: `DateTime` values are only 8 bytes, so you only need 8 bytes to create a unique `Guid` from a `Datetime` that will always convert back.

Comment: From reading the info about versioning it seems this will only matter when working with distributed systems? Any other risks here? @spender ?

Comment: Since I'm working with a record that doesn't care about the node of creation or any of the other metadata of standard guids and if this guid isn't the most secure value that's fine. This seems perfectly reasonable for my use case.

Comment: A few searches later it seems you could run into issues when converting your guid between types and different systems. This error implies going to 16 bit binary could cause truncation of trailing zeros which would be very bad. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538448/binary16-field-is-truncating-guids-trailing-zeros