# Binary(16) field Is truncating Guid's trailing zeros

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, guid

In C#, I have a `byte[]` field called UniqueId. I store this field as a Binary(16) in a SQL Server database (EF6).

I have noticed that sometimes, the stored guid is 15 bytes instead of 16 bytes. This causes the following exception when I do `var guid = new Guid(uniqueId)` after retrieving the value from the db:

> System.ArgumentException : Byte array for GUID must be exactly 16
>   bytes long.

After investigating this, I noticed that whenever my generated guid contains "00" at the end of the hex, SQL truncates it!

Example:

**Generated Guid (via Guid.NewGuid):** FF96F954777E8941A04774CD157C5C00 (16 bytes)

**Stored Binary(16) in SQL Server**: 0xFF96F954777E8941A04774CD157C5C (15 bytes)

If you notice, the `00` at the end is truncated. As a result, if I query this field and try to convert its bytes to a Guid, I'll get a `System.ArgumentException`.

Is anybody else experiencing this problem? What is the workaround? I am thinking about a wrapper for `Guid` that keeps generating guids until it doesn't have trailing zeros, but that seems hacky.

Update 1: Since you guys requested it, I ran the SQL profiler, and this is the SQL generated by EF (abridged version):

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[customers]([UniqueId])
VALUES (@0)',N'@0 varbinary(max)',@0=0xFF96F954777E8941A04774CD157C5C00
```

Comment: Can you provide a repro, or at least the code you are using to save the binary data?

Comment: I don't think this is SQL Server, as `SELECT CONVERT(binary(16),0xFF96F954777E8941A04774CD157C5C00)` returns the correct value, as does `SELECT CONVERT(binary(16),0xFF96F954777E8941A04774CD157C5C)`.

Comment: why are you not using `uniqueidentifier` datatype any way?

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree that it is supposed to be `uniqueidentifier`, but the architect of this application decided to use `binary(16)` years ago, and we can't change it :(

Comment: This sounds like an EF issue, a quick test running an insert into SQL seems to faithfully return the 16 bytes.

Comment: what is the ansi padding specification for the column? and is it binary or varbinary?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sure thing. See update #1. I have provided the SQL that is generated by EF.

Comment: @VinShahrdar wow, I take it back; Martin is absolutely correct - TIL!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You see this behaviour with `BINARY(16)` if the `ANSI_PADDING` setting for the column is `OFF` and the column allows `NULL` ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b244f1563ca1a81481f835d7e7a60b6e)).

Fixing it would ideally involve changing the table definition so the column is using `uniqueidentifier` datatype or at least has `ANSI_PADDING` on.

To change the `ANSI_PADDING` semantics will involve `SET ANSI_PADDING ON` then adding a new `binary(16)` column - populating it from the old column and then a drop and rename. And this is if your application can tolerate a possible reordering of columns, if it can't cope with this reordering and `UniqueId` is not the last column in the table you will need to create a new table and migrate all data across.

Comment: I have to admit, I was incredulous about this, but: I hopped into SSMS, created a table with `ANSI_PADDING` off, and ... you're absolutely right. Apparently this "feature" doesn't affect table-variables, only "real" tables. TIL. Just... wow.